# Is this Q on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

[Is there a difference between a spaceship and a starship?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10833/is-there-a-difference-between-a-spaceship-and-a-starship)

I'm tempted to close as "General Reference" as it stands.

Comment: Since Q is a character in ST:TNG, a known SF show, Q is always on topic.

Comment: Why didn't you vote to close?

Comment: @Gilles - because I'm not fully convinced that this is off-topic as per rules. I try NOT to buck the community rules as we discussed, though I may work towards changing the rules I disagree with on Meta :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm rather tempted to close as off-topic. This is a question about English words, best researched in a dictionary. Granted, in theory, there could be something to say about the way SF writers use these words, but are there actually interesting patterns?

Comment: Did I hear Gilles just ask a "Are there" question? \**Running to check nearest Hell meterological station*\* :)